# Encrypted home breaks on login

Tags: encryption, login, ecryptfs

My home is encrypted, which breaks the login. Gnome and other services try to find all sorts of `.files`, write to them, read from them and so on. E.g. `.ICEauthority`. They are not found (yet) because at that moment the home is still encrypted. I do not have automatic login set, since that has known issues with encrypted home in Ubuntu.

When I go trough the following steps, there is no problem:

1. boot up the system.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login.
3. run `ecryptfs-mount-private`
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, done. Can now login.

I may have some setting wrong, but have no idea where. I suspect  `ecryptfs-mount-private` should be ran earlier in bootstrap, but do not know how to make it so.

Some issues that may cause trouble:

- I have a fingerprint reader, it works for login and PAM.
- I have three keyrings in seahorse, containing passwords from old machines (backups). Not just one.

Suggestion was that the PAM settings are wrong, so here are the relevant parts from `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so 
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

I am not sure about how this configuration works, but ut seems that maybe the **optional** in  `auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap` is causing the `ecryptfs` to be ignored?

Comment: PAM is reponsible for the ecryptfs decryption task when a user logins, so it's most likely related to the fingerprint reader. Check the for the ecryptfs options defined at /etc/pam.d/ , you may need to tweak them.

Comment: I have added a few lines from the /etc/pam.d/common-auth to the question above. I don't see anything immediately.

Comment: @João Pinto: can you copy-paste your comment as an answer? then I can accept it. It was indeed the combination of ecryptfs and fingerprint that causes the problem. Disabling fingerprint-login solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAM is reponsible for the ecryptfs decryption task when a user logins, so it's most likely related to the fingerprint reader.

Check the for the ecryptfs options defined at /etc/pam.d/ , you may need to tweak them.

Comment: Disabling fingerprintreader solves the issue. Thanks for the help, you have brought me a lot further in this issue.